# value of Global Variables got overwritten while Dynamic loading of executables in mips_linux_uclibc_gcc compiler

Tags: c, linux, mips, dynamic-loading

I have an application (application1) which dynamically loads other applications using dlopen in linux kernel 2.6.31 in a mips processor. The compiler I'm using is mips_linux_uclibc_gcc.

The application1 contains a global variable say (int dynamic_variable ) and it's assigned some value . After this assignment I dynamically load another application (application2) which contains a global variable with same name (int dynamic_variable) and if I assign some value to this variable, the value of the variable in application1 also gets changed.

The address of the global variable in application1 and application2 are same .So they refer to the same address in Atheros Board , but in Ubuntu 12.04 they are different.

In Ubuntu 12.04 the address in the application2 is same as the one I got using the api dlsym(handle,"dynamic_variable") while dynamically loading application2 . So I got to know the appliation2 is refering to its own global variable but in Atheros its refering to application1's global variable .

I thought global variables will be in the global name space and wont be overwritten but I'm getting a different result. But in ubuntu 12.04 with gcc compiler it works fine; the value of variables didn't get replaced.

Is it something related to dl library implemented in the mips processor or its compiler specific ?